# Statistical analysis for sensory datasets

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I am relatively new to statistics and dealing with a dataset where I’ve studied 3 different treatment groups on color change in bell peppers.
I scored the bell peppers every day for one week based on their skin color (score 1, score 2…score 7) and wanted to see if there are differences in the treatment groups on any given day based on the scores? A lower score (score 1) would mean that bell peppers any not ripening.

I was thinking of performing a chi-share test (kruskal-Wallis) where I create a frequency distribution table and then use a post-hoc test (Dunn test?) to see which group is significantly different. Is my approach statistically okay? Are there any alternative test that you would recommend?

Comment: I think you have some dependence structure in you data that would make it incorrect to just use some tests like Kruskal-Wallis out of the box, and these tests would even miss important information.

Comment: To answer your question completely, one would need to know: can your day-to-day data be considered as data from the same individual? was it the same fruit scored every day, or the same view of a greenhouse? How many individuals (fruits/plants/greenhouses) were scored? To find the optimal test for your problem, it would also be important to know in which way one would expect the treatments to act: is it perhaps the speed of ripening, that is affected?